ABS Bleeding, is it more difficult than the master cylinder?
My vehicle, a 2012 Honda Civic, has an ABS Pump on it. It needs to be disconnected. To prime this pump there is a code that can be sent from a special two-directional ODBII device. In the Hanes book, it doesn't detail this process -- it just assumes you'll involve the dealership.
Other than needing a $100 ODBII device to engage the ABS pump, is it any harder or more-special to prime an ABS Pump than a master cylinder. It seems like it's just another annoying tool you need because there is no manual button on the ABS pump to engage it?

Yes, more difficult to bleed the abs unit than the brake system. Complexity of brake fluid passages and motor creating hydraulic pressures within the abs unit takes over braking no longer controlled by the driver. Specific procedures are followed to bleed the abs unit.  Abs is invisible to brake hydraulics in everyday braking. This allows almost anyone to flush/bleed brakes. When panic braking occurs or tire traction is lost, abs takes over hard braking to control each tire from locking up. As mentioned in your other post, abs is not diy friendly, requiring above average skills and knowledge.

Take it to a local garage - they have the equipment to bleed the system from scratch.
Also, braking systems need the fluid replaced every two, or three, years (approximately) but not many people know this or do it, even some dealers don't do it.
I had my local garage do this for my x-type and it took the 20 minutes, plus a couple of litres of fluid... Good for peace of mind, just asked them to do it with the "normal" service.

Myself, I don't think "take it to a garage" is a valuable contribution. I'd rather die in fire from failed ABS than admit defeat. "Victoria aut mors." - Saint YOLO

@EvanCarroll Ignore Solar Mike's advice at your own peril. I've been doing all my own repairs since the 70s but I have a pre-screened and fully vetted garage lined up for when the day eventually comes that a repair is beyond my abilities. Best of luck to you.
